# Multiple Related Lists

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, case, account

My organization is trying to edit some of our related lists in a way that I'm not sure is possible. Essentially, we have a number of Opportunities and Cases associated with various Accounts. These opportunities are already set up to show in a related list view at the Account level, but what we want to be able to do is also have a related list at the Case level for them. Basically if Opp X is associated with Account Y, and Case Z is also associated with Account Y, we want a related list at the Case level that knows to display Opp X. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure thing. You don't even need `Apex`. Create the following `Visualforce Page` and you can include it in any `Page Layout` you wish on the `Case` object.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!Case.AccountId}" list="Opportunities" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @Adrian: Is it possible to include a filter also, e.g. only opportunities > 50% probability?

Comment: @Fred I believe that requires a switch to `Apex`.